# Config rate limit period for AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, config, amazon-waf

I need a rule for my endpoint "/signup". When you try to signup with a number, you can’t try to signup until the next 1 minute. You have to wait 60 seconds, before submitting a new number.
I am requested to use AWS WAF, but WAF only allows a config rate limit with a period of 5 minutes, I cannot find where I can config for once per minute.

Can I config this rate limit on WAF? Where to config? Or another way to get my purpose?

Thanks everyone